# Overriding CSS styles

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Lets say I put the following in `<body>`

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/2059.js"> </script>
```

looking at that js file, the first line is:

```
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://gist.github.com/stylesheets/gist/embed.css"/>')
```

I don't have write permission to that js file.  Is it possible to dynamically swap out embed.css and swap in the href to another version of that CSS file?  Can this be done such that it requires no user input - the page will load with my own CSS file and not embed.css?

Comment: It's a gist. Fork it and edit as necessary.

Comment: Any reason you don't take the JS file and host it locally?

Comment: @nrabinowitz - the js file is auto-generated from a gist.  Its not the content I'm concerned with, but the display of the gist.  I'm trying to swap out the default display to substitute my own.  The forking solution doesn't work for this.

Comment: @Prescott - There is a good reason, I want to host my code on Gist and Gist does the magic-behind-the-scenes parsing of a code file into div classes that are specific to each language.  So I want Gist to do its thing, I just want to swap in my own embed.css to colorize the code the way I want to

Comment: the JS is just building HTML and adding a CSS file. Just copy those files and host them personally. I don't see a reason why you would want to keep them hosted there. And if you really want to host them there, why not create your own copy?

Comment: @Joseph - I plan to create many code samples.  It would be cumbersome to always have to copy/paste to my host.  And what happens when I update the Gists?  I'd have to update it on my side as well.  Too manual/error prone.  I'm just trying to pick better colors for the syntax highlighting.

Comment: To whomever downvoted/voted for close - I'm asking a legitimate question here.  Either it is or is not possible to swap out the CSS dynamically.  This is a valid programming question.

Comment: @SFun28 the problem is that those links will not stay hosted forever. the same reason why posters in stackoverflow require you to post code in the answer than just link a fiddle. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114944 - which means host your own code if you don't want it to disappear

Comment: @Joseph - You sure?  I think Gists stay around forever.  If not it would wreak havoc on the links to the gists.  All gists are repositories.  I can't see GitHub deleting repositories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest option here is going to be to load your own CSS in a way that will override the Gist CSS - this is going to be much simpler than trying to dynamically change the code Gist provides. Two options for this:

- Add `!important` to your CSS declarations.
- Use the same selectors as the Gist CSS, but prefix them with another selector to make them more specific than the Gist CSS declarations, e.g. `mycontentarea .gist-syntax .c`

The second option is probably going to be more reliable, as long as you know a selector for an enclosing element. See a working example here (I've replaced the standard Gist string color with a nasty yellow): http://jsfiddle.net/aqGEc/